# i want to apply custom type of slider in my app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here is my image, I want to create this type of slider in  my project

[image]

please suggest me about this question

Comment: my image link is here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsWqL.png

Comment: Does this mean, 1km and 10km always be fixed on ui

Comment: you can this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider

Comment: yes @YeasinSheikh 1km to 10km is  always fixed

Comment: @MoklesurRahman pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider is not support null safty 
 i use latest  flutter version so this package is not usefull  for this project

Comment: try with `CustomPaint` and `Stack`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh how  to apply CustomPaint and Stack   on this 
please suggest

Comment: Instead of `please suggest me about this question` -- please tell what your issue is, what kind of help you need etc. And do that by using the [edit] link. Don't add stuff in comments, those will get missed by people trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to achieve can be done with this null-safe Flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_sliders